# In chrome debugger, is there a way to break if any line in a file is executed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I inherited a large, complex file to maintain. It has complicated interactions and couplings with external components (public methods, callbacks, subscriptions and the like). I am trying to find out which lines of code are executed when an action is taken.

Is there an easier way to (in essence) add a breakpoint to every line in a large file? Or is there a more useful way to track how line in a file are activated? Like I would absolutely love a heat-map that would light up the sections of code when they get activated...

Comment: Why would you need it on every line in a file? You can't start executing a file in the middle. When you load the script, all the top-level executes, after that it only executes at the beginning of functions.

Comment: I don't know of a way to automate it, but you just need to put breakpoints on the first line of every function.

Comment: While you can't start executing a file in the middle, the middle of a function might be registering a callback with an external module. At a later time I am executing an action and want to see if any of these callbacks (as well as top-level functions) are called.

Comment: The middle of a function can't be a callback. The callback will be another (possibly anonymous) function, put the breakpoint at the beginning of that nested function.

Comment: Make a recording in performance profiler then sort it by URL, find yours and you'll see its functions in "bottom-up" panel, then place breakpoints accordingly to their time usage.